# How to make an FLV flash movie file trigger calling an URL when the movie is played?

Tags: flash, tracking, flv, flvplayback

We're making a viral video which is going to be distributed as FLV movie file free for download and redistribution.

I don't know much about flash yet but I can imagine FLV is just some sort of special flash application which can also include arbitrary code.

Is it possible to track how many times that movie file has been played by letting the FLV file perform a server-callback when playback begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The FLV format is just a Sorenson Spark encoded video, which is essentially a variant of h.263.

It is possible to embed meta-data in an FLV in the form of cue-points, but this cannot contain self-executing code, and has to be caught and handled by the video player.  If you want to perform any tracking or actions from your video, you need to have control over the player itself AFAIK.

As an alternative, you could look into embedding the video within an SWF for distribution.  While this would give you the ability to execute code you would sacrifice the ability to stream the video, which would make it less usable.